# Equation in integral form

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, indefinite-integrals

I've been working with this equation where the unknown factor is the function $f$ that can be complex:

$$1 = f(\vec{x})\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\ d^3y\ \frac{f(\vec{y})}{|\vec{x} - \vec{y}|^4}$$

Is there any way to solve this equation without using the trial-error method, i.e., without testing different forms for $f$? Anyway, can you see any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there not a problem with the integral when $y=x$?

Comment: I don't follow you, what do you want to say?

Comment: Forget solving for $f$, I don't see how you choose a $f$ so that the integral is finite for any $x$, but maybe that's my lack of vision.

Comment: How do we deal with the singularity at $y=x$?

Comment: Well, from the point of view of the integral $x$ is just a parameter, so for integration I think you can suppose $x \neq y$

Comment: @user121049 yeah, me neither. If you change to spherical coordinates at the end you will have to integrate $f(\vec{y})/\vec{y}^2$ (fixing $x = 0$) but I don't see how to make this convergent

Comment: @Vicky, you are integrating over the *whole real space*, you can't suppose $x \neq y$, unless $x$ doesn't belong to $\mathbb{R}^3$... Maybe you are searching for the principal value of the integral? I have no idea how to deal with this

Comment: @YuriyS Yeah, you are right, I don't know why I thought that. Too many time in front of this problem. Thanks for the correction!